# Java Best practice when an exception in caught into java code function

Tags: java

I'd like to know what is the best way or best-practice to handle this kind of situation. Guess a straightforward function like this:

```
public Object f1() {
    Object result = null;
    try {
        String payload = methodThrowsAnException();         
        result = payload;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'd like to know if it's a good practice:

1. to `re-throw` the exception or
2. return a `null` when something has been wrong inside.

I don't know if I've explained so well.

Comment: If you want to rethrow the exception you should not catch it in the first place, unless you need custom code in between. You can return null in case of exception if it fits your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Re-throwing caught exception is a bad idea. most often, the stacktrace will contain more or less detailed information about your architecture. This would be to useful for an attacker.

I wouldn't allow my app to get into illegal state because of the user's action. In your case, I would say:

```
try {
    String payload = methodThrowsAnException();

    result = payload;
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(<user's input which caused the exception>);   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with returning a null from your method if there is a particular scenario where you expect that exception.

Alternatively you can just allow the Exception to bubble up, and be handled by the caller.

When would I catch and re-throw an exception? When I can convey better meaning by throwing a new exception.

Would I include the original exception when I throw a new one? I would do it if it is a unknown/unexpected scenario which requires further debugging.

Let me share some examples:

1. Something unrecoverable like Out of DB Connection. I would just let the exception bubble up. It should get handled just before it reaches the user, and probably end up in a generic error message like 'Service not available. Please try again later'.
2. Something application related... such as backup file not found. In that case I will swallow up the `FileNotFoundException` and instead I will throw a `BackupFileMissingException` which is specific to my application. Here I don't need to include the `FileNotFoundException` because it is an expected scenario and there is nothing further to investigate.
3. I call some other API and they throw an exception, which is not documented. In this case, I will translate it into my application exception such as `InterfaceApiException` and include the original exception, so that it can be logged at the REST/Action layer along with the root cause.